# Assign categories to pages and display it in the URL slug

Tags: wordpress

i found out what code to use to assign categories to pages (https://hamzashatela.com/3-ways-to-add-categories-and-tags-for-wordpress-pages/), but i wonder if any of you may know if it is also possible to add the category slug on the page URL ? example site.com/category/page ?

thanks!